# How to display system.out.print() in textPane

Tags: jtextpane

I have a printHelp() in my Game class, and I am trying to display it in my GameGUI class in textPane. I got an error message because printHelp() returns void type. Could anyone have a suggestion? Thanks a lot!

```
JTextPane textPane = new JTextPane();
contentPane.add(textPane, BorderLayout.CENTER);
textPane.replaceSelection("whatever printed in printHelp() needs to be displayed here.");


protected void printHelp()
{
    System.out.println("You are lost. You are alone. You wander");
    System.out.println("around at the university.");
    System.out.println("");
    System.out.println("Your command words are:");
    parser.showCommands();
}
```

Comment: What is the error message?

Answer (score 0):

Replace your printHelp method by this :

```
protected String printHelp()
{
    String message = "You are lost. You are alone. You wander"
    +"\n"+"around at the university."
    +"\n"
    +"\n"+"Your command words are:";
    message += parser.showCommands();
    return message;
}
```

And then :

```
textPane.replaceSelection(printHelp());
```

Or if needed, use :

```
private void printBoth() {
    String message = printHelp();
    textPane.replaceSelection(message);
    System.out.println(message);
}
```